# Redirect .htaccess on a special Query_string

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have 2 Files
1.) index.php
2.) index_intern.php

Both Files do the same: they including files in a subdirectory. Only different, the index_intern.php will ask for an Basic Authentification.

Now i want to write a redirect which will forward the user from file 2.) to 1), if a predefined Query String is not respected.

The predefined Query_String where the redirect shall not be performed, looks like this: ?doc=intern/<.*>

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index_intern\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^(doc=intern/.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^index_intern.php$  index.php%{QUERY_STRING} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: So what is the actual question here? What did you try, what error's did you get?

Comment: What is not working for you?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index_intern\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^doc=intern/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^index_intern.php$  index.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [R=301,L]
```

with `?` after `index.php`